# how to update the fields of a MongoDB document when the modified fields are not always the same?

Tags: java, mongodb, jax-rs, quarkus, quarkus-panache

Let's say I have a Foo class and an jax-rs FooResource that exposes an API to CRUD Foos.

Foo represents a MongoDB document.

In FooResource, I'll have something like this:

```
@PATCH
@Path("{id}")
public Response update(@PathParam("id") ObjectId id, Foo foo) {
    return Response.ok(fooService.update(id, foo)).build();
}
```

The problem is that the foo object in json will only contain the fields that have changed, but I never know upfront what fields it will be.

I use the Quarkus with Panache extension and the only way I see is to retrieve the entity from the DB, and then check every single field in the foo object I received from the http request to see if it's null or not, and if not, set the new value in the entity and at the end, call update() on it.

But that would become a nightmare if I have a class with dozens of fields.
It's such a common use case that I can't imagine (or don't want to believe) that this is the only way to do this.

If there was a way to send an incomplete document to MongoDB so that it will take care of changing only the fields present in this document it would be perfect. But I didn't find a way to do this. Neither with quarkus (with or without panache), nor with the java driver for mongo API.

So is there an easier way to do this? I prefer a solution with the quarkus MongoDB with Panache extension but a solution without Panache or even directly with the java driver API would be ok.

PS: sending the full object from the frontend and replacing the whole document is not an option for me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `update(updateDocument, updateParams).where(query, params)` method, it provides a more flexible update method.

From the example from the documentation guide:

```
// set the name of all living persons to 'Mortal'
long updated = Person.update("name", "Mortal").where("status", Status.Alive);
```

For your use case, the query part is on the `_id` field, but you still need to dynamically build the update part based on the field presence of your `Foo` object.

As you said, there is no way to do this easily thought the Java client as when you use typed collection (a collection bind to a Java type and not to a `Document`) null value fields should be reflected to the database (how can the MongoDB client knows that null means don't update the field sometimes or update the field to null).

So for this use case you can :

- Forge an update `Document` with the needed fields (this is what ``update(updateDocument, updateParams).where(query, params)` do for you).
- Get the entity first, merge it manually (you can easily create a reflection based helper for that), then update it.

Comment: Thanks for you answer (and thanks for the extension :)) . Indeed I thought of using reflection for this. I just wanted to avoid it because of Quarkus but it will really help here because I will have classes with a lot of fields so I'll go for it.

Comment: Reflection will not be an issue for GraalVM if you're concerned about it as we register all entity types for reflection. If you use a DTO you can add the `@RegisterForReflection` annotation.